# Playing HEVC(H.265) file using AVPlayer from a remote url

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, ios11, h.265

I am trying to play an HEVC(H.265) codec media url on AVPlayer. But the video is not showing. I didn't get any solution. How do I implement this in ios?

```
let videoURL = URL(string: "http://bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/content/dataset/multi-codec/hevc/stream_fmp4.m3u8")
let avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController() 
playerViewController.player = avPlayer 
self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) { 
    playerViewController.player!.play()
}
```

Comment: Just an obvious question - are you testing against os/devices with support for HEVC?

Comment: Let me rephrase the question. `AVPlayer` can only play content based on available codec support on each device. HEVC is supported only from iOS11 and only on devices with A10+ chips. Reason why I am asking if you are targeting such devices.

Comment: yes. I targeted to device from iOS 11 and A10+ chips

Comment: I am checking on iPhone 7 plus with same configuration, but video is not playing. Do you have any code snippet.?

Comment: I would suggest that you share your code - mainly relevant parts with `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerLayer` setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your example I am able to play this content on a device (not simulator)

> Pay attention also that I changed the URL from HTTP to HTTPS!

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let videoURL = URL(string: "https://bitmovin-a.akamaihd.net/content/dataset/multi-codec/hevc/stream_fmp4.m3u8")
    let avPlayer = AVPlayer()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL!)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        avPlayer.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)

        let avLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avLayer.frame = view.bounds
        view.layer.addSublayer(avLayer)
        avPlayer.play()
    }

}
```

**NB:**

**The container format for HEVC video MUST be fMP4.**

There are a few ways to deliver HEVC content to users:

- HEVC in HLS using MPEG-2 Transport Stream chunks, which Apple doesn’t
  support
- HEVC in HLS using fMP4 segments, which is what Apple    announced on
  WWDC17 and our player supports
- HEVC in MPEG-DASH using fMP4 segments

For reference:
[WWDC17 – HEVC with HLS – Apple just announced a feature that we support out of the box](https://bitmovin.com/wwdc17-hevc-hls-apple-just-announced-feature-support-box/)

[HLS Authoring Specification for Apple Devices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices)